# Column of datatype RowVersion is turned into a column of datatype Timestamp

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server is turning column of datatype RowVersion into a column of datatype timestamp.

i.e. I write table create as:

```
USE [AllanFordKeyTestDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AJF2_Accounts3](
    [ID123]  [RowVersion] NOT NULL)
GO
```

then I use menu options Script table as create to new query window and I get back this:

```
USE [AllanFordKeyTestDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AJF2_Accounts3]    Script Date: 14/10/2019 4:13:50 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AJF2_Accounts3](
    [ID123] [timestamp] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Is this normal?

```
select @@version gives me
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU14) (KB4484710) - 14.0.3076.1 (X64)   Mar 12 2019 19:29:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Even though the docs state the `TIMESTAMP` syntax is deprecated, it is still the internal name of the type (and likely will be for some time), and the various scripters still use it when they ought to have switched to `ROWVERSION`. This could be filed as a bug against Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowversion` is the new name for the older `timestamp`data type. They basically are the same data type, so it's not a case of turning one into the other.

Some of the drivers still use the old name. Many of us have complained to Microsoft about this for quite a while. Because of a desire to not break backwards compatibility, I can't see it changing too soon.